# Creating an array setting the keys as strings

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, key

I have this loop, where I'm trying to generate an array like this:

```
array( $file['file_type'] => $file['import_status] )
```

To do so, I build this foreach loop to access the $file variable, which has the data I wanted to store.

```
$filesStatusArray = array();
foreach ($filesToImport as $keys => $file) {
    $filesStatusArray = $file['import_status'];
}
```

This way I'm doing, I have only an array with the import_status values.. but I wanted the key to be the file_type... how can I do that?

Comment: Probably best to show the structure of the `$filesToImport` array and the desired structure of `$fileStatusArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filesStatusArray = array();
foreach ($filesToImport as $keys => $file) {
    $filesStatusArray[$file['file_type']] = $file['import_status'];
}
```